# Sonar 2.9 does not import SuppressionFilter

Tags: sonarqube, checkstyle, static-code-analysis

I am trying to create new rules profile in Sonar 2.9 with my checkstyle rules xml. When I try to import a checkstyle rules file with suppression filter configured, sonar gives me following messages:

```
Profile 'test2' created. Set it as default or link it to a project to use it for next measures.   [hide]
Checkstyle filters are not imported: SuppressionCommentFilter
Checkstyle filters are not imported: SuppressionFilter   [hide]
```

I am not bothered about SuppressionCommentFilter for now, but how to enable SuppressionFilter? If it is not possible, is there any other way to have a similar functionality of excluding specific files from specific checks in Sonar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [set the Suppression(Comment)Filters manually](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-738):
Go to Configuration -> General Settings -> Java -> CheckStyle. There's an input box. Paste the `<module>` definition from your checkstyle.xml file into the input box. Relative paths are interpreted from the .sonar folder. This feature is present in your 2.9, I think it was added on 2.3.

For all my purposes, this feature was sufficient. To my knowledge, it is not possible to actually *import* the filter module definitions. Might be a newer version of Sonar can do it though.

Comment: Thanks Thomas for the answer. Just one correction, I think the path is relative to current directory, which in most cases is the parent directory of the project. Taking cue from your answer, I manually mentioned the path inside .sonar folder in the configuration, that way the current directory looks cleaner..! :)