# How to use existing Checkstyle files in SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, checkstyle

My co-workers and I would like to incorporate SonarQube into our existing projects.  Our normal development process for Java projects involves running Checkstyle on code changes to ensure they follow our style rules, committing the project to our code repository and having Jenkins build and package the latest version.  We’d like to add SonarQube to this final step (through the Jenkins plugin) but we don’t want to duplicate all of our Checkstyle rules in SonarQube, since this would require us to maintain two separate sets of rules and make things more complicated if we need to make changes to the rules.  We don’t want to completely switch to SonarQube since we’d like to still run Checkstyle before we commit code to our repository.  We’d also prefer to maintain our own Checkstyle files as the main set of style rules as opposed to maintaining the style rules on SonarQube and downloading the generated XML files for our local development.

So is there any way to “upload” (so to speak) our existing set of Checkstyle XML files to SonarQube for it to use in its evaluation?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, it is not possible to have Sonar use the Checkstyle definitions from the repository. Is *is*, however, possible to have Sonar use the current Checkstyle suppression filter from the repository.

As for the rules definitions, I think you will have to maintain them in Sonar, and when anything is changed, also change the copy in the repository which is used by eclipse-cs. This is redundant, but at least it affects only one person - the rest of the team can reap the benefits. This approach also enables intentional differences, e.g. when some Eclipse-specific issue is checked (say, something concerning source folders, which don't exist in Sonar).

The path to the suppressions filter file can be [configured in Sonar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8623006/1005481) to refer to the location where your stuff is checked out for Sonar analysis. So that part can be maintained in the repository without any redundancy.

Answer (score -1):

From my point of view, you should make a choice: use SonarQube or Checkstyle but not both.
Checkstyle on code changes to ensure they follow our style rules => Can't you replace this step with SonarQube. See for example: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Using+SonarQube+in+Eclipse or http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Issues+Report+Plugin

Comment: Since we're running SonarQube after the code has been committed then bad code would be in our repository, which we don't want.

Comment: The SonarQube Eclipse plugin and the Issues Report plugin are there to check your code before committing it to the SCM.